# AWS CodeCommit Public Repository

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, repository, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

Currently I'm trying to grant public read access to a Git repository in AWS CodeCommit without any access control. All references I was able to find, explain the access configuration possibilities in IAM, but as IAM needs a registered user with credentials this can't be considered public. Is there any possibility to configure public read access to a repository or is this just impossible in AWS CodeCommit?

Answer (score 10):

No, unfortunately it is not currently possible to configure AWS CodeCommit repositories to be public. They can only be accessed by users setup in IAM policies and groups.

Github and Bitbucket allow you to host public repositories.

References:

- https://www.unixdaemon.net/cloud/aws-codecommit-initial-thoughts/
- http://www.solutionsbyraymond.com/2015/12/29/getting-started-with-aws-codecommit/

Comment: Is there any AWS service to share public versioned code repository?

Comment: I'm sure you could use S3 to share code or sync it to github

Comment: true S3 has versioning